# What is the correct way to download a file with selenium webdriver and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm just trying to simply download a file using python/firefox/selenium. The file is been downloaded, but I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timeout loading page after 300000ms
```

I suppose that my wait definition is not correct. My code looks like that:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
wait.until(driver.get(downloadLink))
```

Comment: Do you already have a list of URLs?

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, I have an url and it is working. And I can download it if I use subprocess.check_call